# Can a javascript string be evaluated as a function without eval?

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm doing a code audit and the `toString` method can be overwriten by an attacker due to an unwanted behavior. It is overwritting the `toString` method with a string rather than a method.

Take the following code :

```
let a = new Object();
a.toString = "function(){ return 'hello world' }"
```

`a.toString` is a string and not a function here. Thus, `a.toString()` won't work.

Is there any hack possible that would result in accidentally executing the `toString` string (considering the string can be anything and not considering eval) ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm doing a code audit and the toString method can be rewriten. Since the input is coming from a client, it's overwritting the toString method of the instance with a string sent by a client. I was wondering if there were any security risk here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is not a wanted behavior but a bug. Rest to discover if this bug is exploitable in some way.

Comment: @AnonBird - Now **that** makes sense. :-) I'd include that too.

Comment: It depends on what the attacker can do and what the rest of the code does with your `a` object.

Comment: @melpomene The whole (every method and attributes) of the object can be overwritten. Since this is a get variable coming from the client, I guess the only used method here is toString. This is a bug bounty  and I don't have access to the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your clarifying comment:

> I'm doing a code audit and the toString method can be rewriten. Since the input is coming from a client, it's overwritting the toString method of the instance with a string sent by a client. I was wondering if there were any security risk here.

Unless your code does something to turn that string into a function (`eval(a.toString)`, `new Function(a.toString)`, `btn.onclick = a.toString;`, ...), it won't become one, so in that sense it's not a security risk. Anything attempting to call `toString` on `a` (explicitly or implicitly) will get an error instead. For instance, here's an implicit use of `toString`:

```js
let a = new Object();
a.toString = "function(){ return 'hello world' }"
String(a); // TypeError: a.toString is not a function
```

It's obviously not desirable, but you said it was a bug and you're trying to explore the degree to which it could be exploited. I'd say it's not particularly exploitable.